# List add extension with properties

Tags: c#, list

I can best explain this by showing a example of what I wish

I have a model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

I make a list

```
List<TestModel> testList = new List<TestModel>
```

now originally when I add a item I should use

```
testList.Add(new TestModel { Test1 = 1, Test2 = "Test" });
```

but what I wish to be able to do is

```
testList.Add(1, "Test")
```

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an extension method to do it, but I wouldn't personally.

```
public static class TestModelListExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this List<TestModel> list, int test1, string test2)
    {
        list.Add(new TestModel { Test1 = test1, Test2 = test2 });  
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestModel> list = new List<TestModel>();
        list.Add(1, "hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain why you wouldn't use this personally?

Comment: If you want to do what you say you do, then I would use this method. However - I wouldn't personally want to do it. I don't feel it adds anything to the code (at least in your simple example) and would likely confuse people, more than help them. I'd personally just stick with the way you're currently adding things. If you really want to do this though, then an extension method is the right way.

Comment: @Levisaxos: Plus, it is really localized, meaning that you will be able to use it only on `List<TestModel>` objects. It can be confusing for people reading your code because it's not a common way to add items to a list. But if you really want to do that, this is the way to go.

Comment: My main reason to do this is because I hate having to use "new TestModel" each and every time. You are both right however on the confusion part and maybe it's better that if I were to use this I should rename it to AddItem or atleast something else than 'Add'?

Comment: If you think it adds something to your code then use it as is if you like. I suspect once you've been using it for a while you'll decide it's not really giving you anything worthwhile though. There may well be a case for using it in your codebase but if your only reason is to not type new then I'd consider whether it was worth it.

Comment: After discussion with my teacher / project manager I decided to not use this method for the public website due to the posibility of confusion. It will however be usefull in my private project which only I will work on.  Thank you for your reply and comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a constructor of your `TestModel` and do:

```
testList.Add(new TestModel(1, "Test"));
```

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }

    public TestModel(int test1, string test2) 
    {
        Test1 = test1;
        Test2 = test2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but it does make it a bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static List<TestModel> Add(this List<TestModel> list, int test1, string test2)   {
        return list.Add(new TestModel { Test1 = test1, Test2 = test2 });
    }
}
```